# Merge & Reformat text

Tags: microsoft-word, notepad++, microsoft-word-2007, pspad

I have a lot of Bible text looks like

> Gen 1:1 In the beginning God created
>   the heavens and the earth.
>   Gen 1:2 The earth was empty, a
>   formless mass cloaked in darkness. And
>   the Spirit of God was hovering over
>   its surface.
>   Gen 1:3 Then God said, "Let there be
>   light," and there was light.
>   Gen 1:4 And God saw that it was good.
>   Then he separated the light from the
>   darkness.

I want each verse to be on it's own line with no ^p marks and remove Book -chapter verse look like this - I have Word 2007-Notepad++ and PsPad to accomplish this - what would be best way to look like this

> In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth.
>   The earth was empty, a formless mass cloaked in darkness. And the Spirit of-
>   Then God said, "Let there be light," and there was light.
>   And God saw that it was good. Then he separated the light from the darkness.-
>   God called the light "day" and the darkness "night." Together these made up-

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use regular expressions to search for patterns and then replace/reformat the text.

Regular Expressions: http://regular-expressions.mobi/index.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved by including an example.

Comment: This is effectively a link only answer. Please expand your answer to include an example on how to achieve this with Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a few tricks with notepad++
*Before You start, You may want to make a backup of your file*

You can format the line breaks for example if You select all text and press **Ctrl + j**, this will make your text into a single line.

example
input:

```
 Gen 1:1 In the beginning God created
 the heavens and the earth.
 Gen 1:2 The earth was empty, a
 formless mass cloaked in darkness. And
 the Spirit of God was hovering over
 its surface.
```

output:

```
Gen 1:1 In the beginning God created  the heavens and the earth.  Gen 1:2 The earth was empty, a  formless mass cloaked in darkness. And  the Spirit of God was hovering over  its surface.
```

Than You can break your text at the end of sentences by opening Search > Replace... (hotkey - **Ctrl + H**), set the search mode to 'Extended', to the 'Find what:' You put: "**.**", and to the 'Replace with:' you write "**.\n**", and press replace all

example
input:

```
Gen 1:1 In the beginning God created  the heavens and the earth.  Gen 1:2 The earth was empty, a  formless mass cloaked in darkness. And  the Spirit of God was hovering over  its surface.
```

output:

```
 Gen 1:1 In the beginning God created  the heavens and the earth.
 Gen 1:2 The earth was empty, a  formless mass cloaked in darkness.
 And  the Spirit of God was hovering over  its surface.
```

---

For getting rid of the 'Gen' part, all You need to do is to change the search mode to Regular Expression, in the 'Find what:' You write "Gen (...) ", and the 'Replace with:' remains empty. Press 'Replace all' and:

input:

```
 Gen 1:1 In the beginning God created  the heavens and the earth.
 Gen 1:2 The earth was empty, a  formless mass cloaked in darkness.
 And  the Spirit of God was hovering over  its surface.
```

output:

```
 In the beginning God created  the heavens and the earth.
 The earth was empty, a  formless mass cloaked in darkness.
 And  the Spirit of God was hovering over  its surface.
```

Answer (score 0):

I live and breathe this stuff. I scan and OCR books to MOBI all the time.

What you want is simple: in your favorite RegEx tool (mine is EditPlus because I can do this for 200 files in an instant) use the following to start (ignore initial space):

```
Replace: ([a-z])\n([a-z])
With: \1 \2
```

Next:

```
Replace: ^([A-Z])([a-z]+) ([0-9]+):([0-9]+)
With: 

That is, blank.
```

You get the idea.